# Sum of weighted independent Bernoulli RVs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose that I have $n$ independent Bernoulli variables $b_i$ with their associated probability of success $p_i$, and a set of corresponding weights $w_i$.

I would like to say something about the distribution of the random variable defined as:
$$ x=\sum_{i=1}^nw_ib_i$$
Is this a known distribution? Are there any useful results about this?

Comment: See Section 3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.2702. "They're hard to learn from samples." (By the way, if all $w_i$'s are equal to 1, this is called a [Poisson Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution).)

Comment: @ClementC. Presumably from the usage of the term "weights" we should assume that the $x$ is a convex combination of the $b_i$, i.e. $w_i\geqslant 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i=1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546366/distribution-of-weighted-sum-of-bernoulli-rvs

Comment: @Math1000 The linked paper assumes the weights are known, so the two are equivalent for the hardness result. You can always renormalize your draws.